Why do we have to use "in" for Typescript unions for type narrowing?
I keep tripping over the use of 'in' when narrowing down union types. And I keep asking myself why we can't just check for the property for the narrowing to work?
Example...
type Obj1 = {
  message: string
}

type Obj2 = {
  text: string
}

const getText = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if (obj.message) { // <- 'message' does not exist on type 'Obj1 | Obj2'
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}

Instead, we have to write:
const getText2 = (obj: Obj1 | Obj2): string => {
  if ("message" in obj) {
    return obj.message
  }

  return obj.text
}

Why?

Why? Because this is not inplemented (yet). However, there are open feature requests such as microsoft/TypeScript#42384. Also note that a truthy check is not logically equal to the in operator. E. g. you would have issues when narrowing optional properties that way as shown in this playground. Does that answer your question? If so, I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicte.

I'd say the canonical feature request for this is ms/TS#1260 (and subsequent feature requests or bug reports have been closed as working as intended or duplicates of this one), and it is very unlikely to happen as per this comment. I'd be happy to write this up as an answer but I don't want to step on @Behemoth

In the case of if (obj.message), there is an additional step of boolean coersion based on truthiness. The if condition requires a boolean expression and obj.message returns a string, so the string must be converted into a boolean.
In contrast, the operators in, instanceof and typeof do not require an extra step of boolean coersion.
These two links are where I found the information:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

@Behemoth's answer in the comments of the question nails this, I was slower and less precise. Good work team!
